# ActionController::UrlGenerationError, No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I've read through every similar question I could find and still can't figure out my problem.

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :lists, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
    resources :items, except: [:new]
  end
end
```

---

```
# items_controller.rb (excerpt)
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

---

```
# items_controller_spec.rb (excerpt)
RSpec.describe ItemsController, type: :controller do
   ...

  let!(:list) { List.create(title: "New List title") }

  let(:valid_item_attributes) {
    { title: "Some Item Title", complete: false, list_id: list.id }
  }

  let!(:item) { list.items.create(valid_item_attributes) }
  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new item" do
        expect {
          post :create, { item: valid_item_attributes, format: :json  }
        }.to change(Item, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

And the RSpec error:

```
1) ItemsController POST #create with valid params creates a new item
     Failure/Error: post :create, { item: valid_item_attributes, format: :json  }
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"items", :format=>:json, :item=>{:title=>"Some Item Title", :complete=>false, :list_id=>1}}
```

The output from `rake routes`:

```
list_items     GET    /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)          items#index
               POST   /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)          items#create
edit_list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
     list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#show
               PATCH  /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
               PUT    /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
               DELETE /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#destroy
```

I can successfully create a new item in an existing list via `curl` which tells me that the route is ok, I must be doing something wrong in my test.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "X-User-Email:admin@example.com" -H "X-Auth-xxx" -d '{ "item": { "title": "new item", "complete": "false"} }' http://localhost:3000/lists/5/items
```

I am really confused. My routes are setup correctly. A `ItemsController#create` method definitely exists. The rest of the tests in `items_controller_spec.rb` pass without issue.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What does `rake routes` say about your items-routes?

Comment: Added the output from `rake routes` (above).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are the fixes I had to make to my tests (`items_controller_spec.rb`). I was not passing the correct hash to `post create:`.

```
  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new item" do
        expect {
          post :create, { list_id: list.id, item: valid_item_attributes, format: :json  }
        }.to change(Item, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "assigns a newly created item as @item" do
        post :create, { list_id: list.id, item: valid_item_attributes, format: :json  }

        expect(assigns(:item)).to be_a(Item)
        expect(assigns(:item)).to be_persisted
      end
    end # "with valid params"

    context "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns a newly created but unsaved item as @item" do
        post :create, { list_id: list.id, item: invalid_item_attributes, format: :json  }

        expect(assigns(:item)).to be_a_new(Item)
      end

      it "returns unprocessable_entity status" do
        put :create, { list_id: list.id, item: invalid_item_attributes, format: :json }

        expect(response.status).to eq(422)
      end
    end # "with invalid params"
  end # "POST #create"
```

Comment: Shoudn't your `ItemsController` be called `Lists::ItemsController`, and live inside a `lists` folder? It seems you're not following the Rails structure convention. I am, and I'm having the same issues.

Comment: The physical location of controller file had nothing to do with my original issue.

Comment: Thanks for the assist! I had to remove params in my case.

Comment: Also note that when you leverage `collections` vs `get/post/etc..` in the `config/routes.rb` - this will determine whether you need to snake or camel case the parameter in your spec.

Answer (score 12):

I've received the same error and fixed it in a different way. I'm using Rails `~> 5.0.7`.

**ROUTES**

This is the output from running `rake routes CONTROLLER=bills`:

```
 Prefix            Verb   URI Pattern                                  Controller#Action
download_site_bill GET    /sites/:site_id/bills/:id/download(.:format) bills#download
        site_bills GET    /sites/:site_id/bills(.:format)              bills#index
                   POST   /sites/:site_id/bills(.:format)              bills#create
     new_site_bill GET    /sites/:site_id/bills/new(.:format)          bills#new
    edit_site_bill GET    /sites/:site_id/bills/:id/edit(.:format)     bills#edit
         site_bill GET    /sites/:site_id/bills/:id(.:format)          bills#show
                   PATCH  /sites/:site_id/bills/:id(.:format)          bills#update
                   PUT    /sites/:site_id/bills/:id(.:format)          bills#update
                   DELETE /sites/:site_id/bills/:id(.:format)          bills#destroy
             bills GET    /bills(/page/:page)(.:format)                bills#index
     download_bill GET    /bills/:id/download(.:format)                bills#download
                   GET    /bills(.:format)                             bills#index
                   POST   /bills(.:format)                             bills#create
          new_bill GET    /bills/new(.:format)                         bills#new
         edit_bill GET    /bills/:id/edit(.:format)                    bills#edit
              bill GET    /bills/:id(.:format)                         bills#show
                   PATCH  /bills/:id(.:format)                         bills#update
                   PUT    /bills/:id(.:format)                         bills#update
                   DELETE /bills/:id(.:format)                         bills#destroy
```

---

**REFERENCE CODE**

```
# controllers/admin/bills_controller.rb (excerpt)

module Admin
 class BillsController < ApplicationController

    ...

    def edit
      authorize(@bill)
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
# spec/controllers/admin/bills_controller_spec.rb (excerpt)

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Admin::BillsController, type: :controller do
 ...

    context 'as an AdminUser' do
      login_admin_user

      it 'loads the bill edit page' do
        request.host = 'admin.example.com'
        get :edit, { id: bill }
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
# Error message

2) Admin::BillsController GET bills/:id/edit as a User redirects to the home page
     Failure/Error: get :edit

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/bills"}
```

---

**POTENTIAL SOLUTION**

I tried variations of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027199/rspec-controllers-in-and-out-of-namespace-with-same-name). It may work for others, but I got this error:

```
Failure/Error: require 'admin/bills_controller'

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- admin/bills_controller
```

**SOLUTION**

I tried Case 2 in [this github issues](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1767) and it worked. The changes I made to my code were to add this `params: { use_route: 'admins/bills/', id: bill.id }`. Below is the context of this addition:

```
context 'as an AdminUser' do
   login_admin_user

   it 'loads the bill edit page' do
     request.host = 'admin.example.com'
     get :edit, params: { use_route: 'admins/bills/', id: bill.id }
     expect(response.status).to eq(200)
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails newbies like me ending up in this thread! How are you?

I have done an innocent mistake that's lead to the same exact error mentioned in this thread. In case you are new and not used to these conventions. Here is the mistake.

Say my route is `/resource/create`. I had written my test as follows:

```rb
RSpec.describe ResourceController do
  describe "POST #create" do
    it "creates a new item" do
        post "/resource/create", { item: item, format: :json  }
    end
  end
end
```

Whereas it should've been:

```rb
RSpec.describe ResourceController do
  describe "POST #create" do
    it "creates a new item" do
      post :create, { item: item, format: :json  } # <--- Here is the diff
    end
  end
end
```

1. The name of the top level describe block, `ResourceController`, defines the root path in your url (`/resource`)
2. Then, `:create` bit is the second part of the URL path. And it has to be a symbol, it doesn't work as a literal string (e.g. `/create`)