# Ruby on Rails RSpec test failing because of routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, curl, rspec

I have been trying to test my index route using RSpec.

I have this code but the error doesn't make sense because I have this route I tried it on the browser and curl, I'm still getting a response.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Spree::Admin::OfficeAddressesController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET index" do
    it "render view index template" do
      get :index, params: {use_route: 'spree/admin/office_addresses'}
      # expect(response).to render_template('index')
      expect(response).to eq(200)
    end
  end

end
```

error msg:

```
Failures:

  1) Spree::Admin::OfficeAddressesController GET index render view index template
     Failure/Error: get :index, params: {use_route: 'spree/admin/office_addresses'}

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"spree/admin/office_addresses", :params=>{:use_route=>"spree/admin/office_addresses"}}
     # ./spec/controllers/office_addresses_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 18.54 seconds (files took 7.55 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/office_addresses_controller_spec.rb:7 # Spree::Admin::OfficeAddressesController GET index render view index template
```

I have tried this SO answers still no luck

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320214/actioncontrollerurlgenerationerror-no-route-matches)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027199/rspec-controllers-in-and-out-of-namespace-with-same-name)

I tried it with curl I get a `200` ok response.

here are my routes

```
bin/rake routes | grep office_addresses

admin_office_addresses GET   
/admin/office_addresses(.:format) 
spree/admin/office_addresses#index
```

```
rails -v
Rails 4.2.6
```

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.6
```

Curl Response:

```
curl --verbose localhost:3000/spree/admin/office_addresses | grep HTTP

* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /spree/admin/office_addresses HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.0
> Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK

< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< X-Runtime: 1.124812
< Vary: Origin
< X-Rack-CORS: miss; no-origin
< Content-Length: 29482
```

This is my first time to use Rspec btw and the documentation is nevermind...

Controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Spree
  module Admin
    class OfficeAddressesController < ResourceController
      def index
        # @ = .all
      end

    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**
If I require the controller I have this error.

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/office_addresses_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require 'spree/admin/office_addresses_controller'

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- spree/admin/office_addresses_controller
# ./spec/controllers/office_addresses_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/controllers/office_addresses_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00022 seconds (files took 0.34632 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

Comment: Are you able to add your controller code here?

Comment: @fidato I just added it. it doenst have a code though.

Comment: @fidato I added another error

Comment: Please add `require "spec_helper"` in spec file and try again.

Comment: @fidato I still get an error.

Comment: refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800122/error-when-trying-to-run-rspec-require-cannot-load-such-file-rails-helper

Comment: Im getting somewhere. lols. I still have an error though. `ununitialized constant spree`

Comment: It sounds really weird that your test load in 18sec..it's really slow, maybe you should have an issue with your configuration. What documentation do you use for setup Rspec ?

Comment: @morissetcl we're are using this. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails is there another documentation better than this?