# Inheriting BaseController causes uninitialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

In my application I have the following files:

app/controllers/api/articles_controller.rb

```
class Api::ArticlesController < Api::BaseController
end
```

app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb

```
class API::BaseController < ApplicationController
  # some codes here
end
```

in my rspec, I have this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Api::ArticlesController do
  it "should do something here"
end
```

But when I run `rspec spec`, I got `uninitialized constant Api::BaseController (NameError)`. Why? I have `base_controller` under `app/controllers/api`. What do I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does you test controller also have same directory structure?

Comment: Yes, `spec/controllers/api/articles_controller_spec.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Syn-text issue:

```
class Api::BaseController < ApplicationController
  # some codes here
end
```

try this :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027199/rspec-controllers-in-and-out-of-namespace-with-same-name

this link will help full to you

Comment: Still no luck with that link.